# $H_n(X \times \{x,y\}, X \times \{x\})\cong H_n(X)$ isomorphism of homology groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $\{x,y\}$ be a (discrete) subspace of the topological space $X$. Do we have an isomorphism
$$H_n(X\times \{x,y\}, X \times \{x\}) \cong H_n(X)$$
between the relative homology group and the usual homology group?

I tried to consider the long exact sequence in which the relative homology group occurs, but could not conclude anything. Maybe some sort of direct sum decomposition does the trick, or some other machinery that I'm missing. I also tried to apply the excision theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you assume $\{x,y\}$ to be discrete, you may use the homeomorphism
$$X\times\{x,y\} \cong X \sqcup X.$$
Under this homeomorphism $X\times\{x\}$ corresponds to the first $X$ in $X\sqcup X$.
Now by excission
$$H(X_{(1)}\sqcup X_{(2)}, X_{(1)}) \cong H(X_{(2)},\emptyset) = H(X_{(2)}).$$

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure that relative homology with the emptyset in the second factor makes sense?

Comment: I think so. One does use the convention $X/\emptyset =: X_{+}$ the space with basepoint added. Hence this means $\widetilde{H}(X_{+}) = H(X)$